# Why do I get different results in IRB and a script?

Tags: ruby

Is there a difference in how IRB and Ruby execute some expressions?

These expressions give different results in IRB and when run from the command line. The question is, which one is correct?

IRB:

```
>> s = 'hello'
=> "hello"
>> s.size
>> s[s.length] = '!'
IndexError: index 5 out of string
    from (irb):31:in `[]='
    from (irb):31
>>
```

And in the normal script:

```
s = 'hello'
s[s.length] = '!'
puts s

laptop user$ ./prgruby.rb 
hello!
```

Comment: The first one worked for me from the irb prompt.  ruby 1.9.2p0 on Windows.

Comment: 1.9.2p290/OSX, neither throws exception.

Comment: Maybe these scripts running in different ruby's. Check it by printing ruby version at runtime.

Comment: Ok guys, so it turns out the error is only thrown in Ruby 1.8* As I said I'm rookie, but this is an interesting find.

Comment: Do you use rvm? Did you do `#!/usr/bin/ruby` or `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`? If you used the former under rvm, you're probably executing two different versions.

Comment: Working in `ruby 1.9.3 p194`. For the record, [`ruby 1.8` is a legacy implementation of the Ruby language](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/) – you should migrate to 1.9 as soon as possible, and be aware that the 2.0 release is already planned and scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_7_72/String/%5B%5D%3D) is the doc of `String#[]` for `1.8.7` :

```
str[fixnum] = fixnum
```

> The forms that take a Fixnum will raise an IndexError if the value is
>   out of range

[Here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) is the same doc for `1.9.3` : the same definition is present

After test, what happen in Ruby 1.9.3 is `s.length` is not out of range for assignation. This make sense at it is the end of the string : you do not have to arbitrary fill the missing indexes but I guess it may be or should be documented somewhere ?

Comment: yes I find these string replacement/assignment/slicing operations a bit odd. For example: s[s.size,1] returns empty string even though we are looking out of range - unless the strings are finalised as in C with '\0' character. s[s.size+1,1] on the other returns nil which could confirm the "string finalisation" theory...anyways would appreciate if someone could give me some hints here...